# Unable to Get SP List Due with Additional Parameter in Url

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint

I am able to retrieve the `List` name of a document library with the following `Document Library`:

```
http://test.com/RecordsDocument/
```

However, I encountered the following error for the following `List`:

```
http://test.com/Lists/FilePlan
```

The difference is the additional `/Lists/` component in the 2nd URL.

Below is my code snippet, may I know how can I tackle this issue?

```
$baseUrl="http://test.com/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl

$RDlistName ="RecordsDocument"    //success
$FPlistName ="Lists/FilePlan"     //failed
//$FPlistName ="FilePlan"         //failed

$RDlist = $web.Lists[$RDlistName] //success
$FPlist = $web.Lists[$FPlistName] //null value

Write-host List Name: $RDlist     //success
Write-host List Name: $FPlist     //null value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use List name inside $web.Lists:

```
$FPlistName ="FilePlan"
$FPlist = $web.Lists[$FPlistName]
```